# Directory /root/Maildir get too big

Tags: maildir

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 22.04 installed hosting a blog website.
I noticed that /root/Maildir/new directory got extremely big (45% of the whole disk).
i can see that alla the files there are email notifications for the root.
Can i safely remove the files in there to gain disk space ?

Comment: Your mailer is misconfigured, see `man -k aliases`. Read the files, with `sudo less` or a mail program. Your system is trying to tell you something. It may be important. If uou don't fix the cause, it'll just fill up sgain